# How to install and configure Magento 2.3.1 on Google Cloud Platform GCP

Tags: magento, google-cloud-platform, magento-2.3

I am a new Magento user. I have been searching for the best cloud environment to host my websites and e-Commerce stores. I have selected GCP but unfortunately, there is no manual or documentation to help me with the installation and configuration.

How to install and configure Magento 2.3.1 on GCP?

Comment: Is this not the installation instructions for that software package?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install-flow-diagram.html

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to configure to Magneto on Google Cloud Platform.
1) First one is you do every things by yourself all the cloud set and setting up Magneto. For example you decide to go with Compute Engine
 - Create a [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/).
 - After create the Compute Engine ssh into the Compute Engine. Follow [Magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html) guide and configure the compute engine.

2) Second way is to use launch a Compute Engine. For that please check Google Market Place . [Google Market Place](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/magento?q=Mangento&id=2808b5cc-0fbc-4d2e-a749-0e4f26c9ae7d)

[Example](https://secureanycloud.com/magento-technical-support-cloud-help-azure-aws-opensource-cognosys/?target=google)